# How to make React-Draggable work with flexbox?

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, draggable

```
  <div className="room">
    <Draggable
      bounds="parent"
      grid={[50,50]}
      handle=".handle"
      onStart= {this.handleStart}
      onDrag= {this.handleDrag}
      onStop= {this.handleStop} >
    <img src={table} className="handle" />
    </Draggable>
  </div>
```

So this is my code for the Draggable component, it's pretty basic. The problem is the Draggable component isn't recognizing the fact that "room" is offset because it's centered by flexbox. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Try removing the `grid` property

Comment: It still doesn't work